# Android adb doesn't work at Ubuntu in VMWare Workstation

Tags: android, ubuntu, adb, offline, vmware-workstation

My host machine runs with Ubuntu 12.04 64bit. On the host `adb` works normal. But in the VM (Ubuntu 12.04 32bit / VMWare Workstation 8.0.4) `adb` shows either no device or device offline. Starting `adb` as `root` doesn't help. 
lsusb shows the device:

```
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 18d1:4e12 Google Inc. Nexus One (debug)
```

Comment: Make sure you have USB 2.0 enabled in the workstation settings (default is sometimes 1.1)

Comment: Sorry, I'm more used to VirtualBox, that's the only suggestion I had :/

Answer (score 5):

You won't see the device in your host + guest simultaneously, only one at a time. For example, if you connect a regular USB drive, you can either have the host be able to use it or one of the guests but not both. Usually, if one of the guest VMs has focus (like when you have clicked on it, have typed, etc.) when you insert it, then the connected device goes to the guest and can't be accessed on from host. It would appear as a connected device on the host but not directly usable. In your case, it's happening the other way round. So...

If it's already connected and detected in the host but not the guest, go to the `VM` menu --> `Removable Devices` --> under the device indicated as "Google Nexus...." select `Connect (Disconnect from Host)`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Sorry maybe the question is badly worded. I know I can use the smartphone only at the host or the guest. The device is connected to the guest and the lsusb output is from the guest.  Additional Infos: If I disconnect & reconnect the device, I can see (and use adb normal) it sometimes at the guest. Unfortunately I have to reboot the device several times and at same time adb shows no device or device offline.

Comment: I don't mean 'disconnect and reconnect' above. I mean using VMware's menu for 'Removable Devices' to tell VM that the device should pass through to the guest instead of the host (and vice versa). I very often plug in a USB drive while working in a VM when i actually meant to connect it to the host. I use the method I described above.

Answer (score 4):

I had a problem with this on my system as well.  Turns out I have USB 3.0 and USB 2.0 ports on my computer.   ONLY the USB 2.0 ports would work.  Luckily my new system has ONE of those.

Not sure if it will help this case, but worth looking into.

BTW, VMWare Workstation 9 supports USB 3.0, but I still had problems with it not recognizing USB 2.0 devices like my HTC phone when I plugged into the USB 3.0 port on the host.

Comment: thanks for posting this, switching to a USB 2 port fixed my connectivity problem